# Change allowed input with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

Hi everybody I´m trying to do a script that changes the allowed input of an input with javascript.

The allowed input should be:

```
[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2}[0-9]{1,5}
```

means `2 x number or letter + 1-5 x numbers`.

This is my code I got so far:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3mDRY/200/)

The thing about that code is it works, but it only allows:

```
[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2}[0-9]{1,4}
```

So 1 more number should be allowed to input.

How do I do this and where's the mistake in my code?

The function works, as you could see, but the problem is It needs to allow 1 more number.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have mistaken your `maxlength` with value `6`. Since, you are expecting maximum of 7 characters, `2 x number or letter + 1-5 x numbers` you need to change your `maxlength` with 7 and it will work for you.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("Flightnumber1");

            function isnum(num1) {
              if (num1 <= 9 && num1 >= 0)
                return 1;
              else
                return 0;
            }
            function setCharAt(str, index, chr) {
              if (index > str.length - 1) return str;
              return str.substr(0, index) + chr + str.substr(index + 1);
            }
            el.onkeyup = function(evt) {

              if (!isnum(el.value.charAt(2)))
                el.value = setCharAt(el.value, 2, '');
              if (!isnum(el.value.charAt(3)))
                el.value = setCharAt(el.value, 3, '');
              if (!isnum(el.value.charAt(4)))
                el.value = setCharAt(el.value, 4, '');
              if (!isnum(el.value.charAt(5)))
                el.value = setCharAt(el.value, 5, '');
              if (!isnum(el.value.charAt(6)))
                el.value = setCharAt(el.value, 6, '');
            };
```

```css
.nav { color: green; }
.selected { color: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="Flightnumber1" name="Flightnumber1" placeholder="Flugnummer" type="text" maxlength="7" pattern="[a-zA-Z-0-9]{2}[0-9]{1,5}" title="3 to 7 characters" required />
```

Comment: We got this already but still thanks, maybe it heps someone else, I´ll check your answer as it´s the best. Thank you for your work and your time :)

Comment: No I need to Thank you :)

Answer (score 3):

Your `input` tag has `maxlength="6"` set on it, that's why it's limited.

Change it to `maxlength="7"` and it'll work as expected.

Comment: I was about to say exactly that :)

Comment: Hahaha, well I would never think about that lol, Thank your very much :)